# Лицензия Windows разрешает использование предустановленных шрифтов в картинках на сайте?

Tags: windows, шрифты, лицензирование

Например, написать что-то шрифтом Arial, сохранить как `image.jpg` и опубликовать на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

Тёма Лебедев рассказывал о претензиях, предъявляемых его студией именно из-за шрифтов, которые использовались в ряде работ. Так что стоит внимательнее читать лицензионные соглашения.
Что касается Windows, в своё время пришлось столкнуться с тем, что MS продвигает политику типа "шрифты лицензируются у их создателей или правообладателей" и могут свободно использоваться лишь внутри системы и её приложений.
На практике это означает, что вы смело можете использовать шрифты, скажем, для печати презентации и ехать с ней на конференцию, но гарантированно не имеете права использовать в коммерческих целях (нам три года назад пришлось менять шрифт в товарном знаке на OFL). Опять же, вероятность претензии к частному пользователю значительно ниже, нежели к компании.
Исходя из этого, формально, вы нарушаете правила лицензирования. поступая так, как вы описали. Но если сайт некоммерческий, посещаемость его не чрезмерно велика, то вероятность претензии низка.
А лучше - пользоваться OFL шрифтами

Comment: Ну, товарные знаки это довольно специфическая тема, там же необходима гос. регистрация и чинуши могут кипы бумаг требовать. Меня же просто картиночки на сайте интересуют, которые вроде как можно, в том числе и для коммерческих целей.

Comment: @Hipster Уточнил у нашего юриста, почему мы не купили (цена вопроса около 80 долларов - для компании смешно) право на использование шрифта у Monotype, а использовали OFL. Ответ был таков: непрозрачность соглашения. Поскольку логотип - суть есть графический объект, мы нарушаем соглашение, даже купив шрифт. Зато на сайте текст можем писать, в принципе, с помощью их шрифтов-  сколь угодно, так как это подпадает под действие лицензии.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно для Arial, насколько я понял, **можно, в том числе и для коммерческих целей**, но нельзя распечатать шрифт в виде картинок и использовать их как замену шрифту.

Правообладателя и лицензию можно посмотреть в самом файле шрифта в `windows/fonts`, в частности для Arial там указано:

> Авторские права: The Monotype Corporation. Описание лицензии: "...You
>   may only (i) embed this font in content as permitted by the embedding
>   restrictions included in this font;".

Не понятно что за ограничения включённые в этот шрифт. Вероятно это отсылка к полной лицензии на шрифт, которую можно найти на официальном сайте компании Monotype:

http://www.monotype.com/legal/eula/

> FONT SOFTWARE END USER LICENSE AGREEMENT
>
> You may embed static graphic images into an electronic document,
>   including a Commercial Product, (for example, a “gif”) with a
>   representation of a typeface and typographic design or ornament
>   created with the Font Software as long as such images are not used as
>   a replacement for Font Software...

Comment: А данная EULA она для купленных шрифтов или для всех, в т.ч. предоставленных третьей стороной?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Ну, другого соглашения я у них не нашёл. Оно такое базовое, описывающее 99 способов свиснуть их шрифт всякими хитрыми путями.

Comment: По идее, Майкрософт не владеет шрифтами, а лишь лицензирует их, поэтому все вопросы — к правообладателю, компании Monotype.

Comment: По-разному, есть шрифты которыми владеет Microsoft, например Calibri, и тогда уже надо искать соглашение на шрифты у самого Microsoft-а, но я думаю что там что то похожее.